Polkit Login Screen issue in Kubuntu 22.04 lts
After yesterdays update, the login screen gets replaced by the dumbest '.. Contact system administrator' message. Ctrl alt F2 etc work fine. There are no issues in the boot messages. Syslog has a few on polkit. Additionally, there was the problem with sudo ...that I fixed with chown chmod. I am on a desktop running no servers. What should I do?

Please ask a clear question. Reading this I have no idea what you are asking.

I think an update messed up polkit permissions

Can you be more specific about the errors you saw? As well, please [edit] your question to include the exact chown/chmod commands that you ran - tbh those are more likely to be the cause of your issue than anything related to polkit
